# Add a constant value to a vector’s elements

Tags: matlab

I would like to add a constant value of 360 to a vector of values after the maximum value is reached. That is, if `H=[12 26 67 92 167 178 112 98 76 85]`, how do I write a matlab code so  that 180 is added to all values after 178? The answer should be `H=[12 26 67 92 167 178 292 278 256 265]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
n=find(H==max(H));
H(n+1:end)=H(n+1:end)+180;
```

Since desired vector values are in increasing order, idea here is to find the index of maximum value and increment all the subsequent elements with 180.

**EDIT**

Better approach for finding max index, as suggested by *@LeonidBeschastny*

```
[~,n]=max(H);
```

Comment: `[~, n] = max(H)` is better.

Comment: And MatLab have no support for `+=`. Not sure about latest `2013`, though.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny thanks for pointing it out. I'm testing on Octave. Compatibility is killing me, it's twice today. It seems Octave is more friendly than MatLab. Edited my ans.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on earlier Matlab versions as well:

```
H=[12 26 67 92 167 178 112 98 76 85]
[n, n] = max(H);
H(n+1:end) = H(n+1:end) + 180
```

Comment: Is `[n, n]` a typo, or it's a backward compatibility for really old MatLab versions (prior to `2009b`, when there was no `~` operator)?

Comment: Actually I thought it was compatible with earlier versions (but it works on mine, which is R2010b).

Comment: `[n, n]` should be compatible with any version of MatLab, it just looks  weird. =)

Comment: Sorry, I meant [~, n] works on mine, while I think [n, n] should work on earlier versions. I remember I had problems with that tilde.

Comment: Yep, they added it in `R2009b`.